# IOS/Objective-C: Testing for nil and opposite

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to test an object property for nil.  When I do following it does *not* throw error:

```
if (item.pic == nil)
{ //do something
}
```

However, when I do negative, it *does* throw error:

```
if (!item.pic == nil)
{ //do something different
}

The error is: Comparison between pointer and integer INT and Void
```

I want the second formulation (although I guess I could reverse everything) however, I would like to understand why one would throw error and other would not.  Can anyone explain this?  Thank you.

Comment: Your second test should be `if (item.pic != nil)`

Comment: Please check my answer and try with `if (YES == nil)`. You will get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second test should be:

```
if (item.pic != nil)
{
    //do something different
}
```

which translates as `if item.pic is not equal to nil`.  In Objective-C this can be shortened to:

```
if (item.pic)
{
    // do something different
}
```

Comment: didn't realize it was that straightforward.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this:

```
if (!(item.pic == nil)) // or if(item.pic != nil)
{ //do something different
}
```

`item.pic == nil`: Comparison between  pointer vs pointer

`!item.pic == nil`: Comparison between  integer vs point -> error. `!item.pic` will return YES/NO (1/0), so can't compare with `nil`